# ¿Cómo puedo corregir este error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'?

Tags: python, bucles, while

Estoy programando un código donde calculo la cantidad requerida de materiales para una construcción, pero me surge un problema al declarar el primer bucle `while`

```
while elige_cantidad < cantidad_requerida
```

Y es que me arroja

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Y no puedo encontrar una solución.

Aquí mi código:

```
print('Tipos de cemento:\n')

def select_cemento(tipos_de_cemento):
        
    print('\n'.join(tipos_de_cemento)+'\n')
    while True:
        selected=input('Elige un código: ')
        if selected in tipos_de_cemento:
            print(f'Has elegido: {tipos_de_cemento[selected]}\n')
            break
        else:
            print('El código no existe, introduce un código válido')
    return selected


def cantidad_cemento(tipos_de_cemento, selected):
    cantidad_requerida = tipos_de_cemento[selected]
    elige_cantidad = 0
    valid_cantidad = False
    while elige_cantidad < cantidad_requerida:
        while not valid_cantidad:
            insert_cantidad_cemento = float(input('Introduce la cantidad de cemento: '))
            if type(insert_cantidad_cemento) is float:
                valid_cantidad=True
            else:
                print('¿Acaso quieres que el universo explote?')    
    
    return cantidad_requerida, elige_cantidad


def main():
    tipos_de_cemento = {'A1': 'Cemento Gris', 'B2': 'Cemento Blanco', 'C3': 'Estuco', 'D4': 'Cemento Impermecem', 'E5': 'Cemento Albañilería'}
    selected_cemento = select_cemento(tipos_de_cemento)
    cantidad_cemento(tipos_de_cemento, selected_cemento)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Me pueden ayudar a corregir este error?

Muchas gracias y saludos!

Comment: Recuerda que si pides un número en un input deberás de convertirlo a entero con `int()` ya que python no sabe qué dato es el ingresado al input por lo que siempre devuelve una cadena, tu error dice que no se puede operar entre enteros y strings, revisa bien tu código

Comment: No, no logro encontrar el problema, me disculpo mucho

Comment: Haz esto `print(type(cantidad_requerida))` y `print(type(elige_cantidad))` y mira cual es el resultado

Comment: El mensaje de error te dice, casi literalmente que, al llegar a la comparación `cantidad_requerida` es una cadena de caracteres y `elige_cantidad` es un entero y ambos tipos no pueden compararse.

Comment: Ok, gracias, ya lo corregí

Comment: Si lo has solucionado, añádela como respuesta para que quede documenado. Intenta simplificar algo el código. Esa comprobación de tipos `float` es innecesaria ahí donde está, además de que es más apropiado usar [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#isinstance) para comprobar tipos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque ya te han dicho en los comentarios que el error es que estás comparando `cantidad_requerida` con `elige_cantidad` y uno es un `integer` y el otro un `string`, te diré de dónde viene tu error.

Si te fijas, el error está en la linea `while elige_cantidad < cantidad_requerida:`, y dos lineas antes defines `elige_cantidad = 0` luego el `string` tiene que ser `cantidad_requerida`.

Cuando haces `selected_cemento = select_cemento(tipos_de_cemento)` lo que estás almacenando en la variable es el código del cemento ('A1', 'B2', 'C3', etc.)
Así que en la siguiente línea es como si estuviese pasando esto (suponiendo que han elegido 'A1'):

```
cantidad_cemento({'A1': 'Cemento Gris',
                  'B2': 'Cemento Blanco',
                  'C3': 'Estuco', 
                  'D4': 'Cemento Impermecem', 
                  'E5': 'Cemento Albañilería'}, 'A1')
```

Así que en la primera línea de la función `cantidad_cemento()` lo que realmente esta haciendo es asígnar el tipo de cemento a `cantidad_requerida`, es decir:

```
cantidad_requerida = tipos_de_cemento[selected]
cantidad_requerida = 'Cemento Gris'
```

Por lo que luego el problema te sale porque comparas `while 0 < 'Cemento Gris':`